# Creating wlan interface on debian 7

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I am running  Debian 7 under VMWare and want direct wifi connection. I have a USB wifi device plugged in and the relevant module (rtl8192cu) seems to be loaded (automatically).

```
root@debian7:~# uname -a
Linux debian7 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@debian7:~# lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
rtl8192cu              74897  0 
rtlwifi                81393  1 rtl8192cu
rtl8192c_common        52602  1 rtl8192cu
mac80211              192806  3 rtl8192c_common,rtlwifi,rtl8192cu
cfg80211              137243  2 mac80211,rtlwifi

root@debian7:~# lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 20f4:648b TRENDnet TEW-648UBM 802.11n 150Mbps Micro Wireless N Adapter [Realtek RTL8188CUS]
```

Yet there is no wlan interface:

```
root@debian7:~# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:2e:d5:3e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.233.215/24 brd 172.16.233.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe2e:d53e/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@debian7:~# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

How do I get the wlan interface to appear? I tried adding it to /etc/network/interfaces without success.

Comment: What about `ifconfig -a`?

Comment: much the same as `ip a` but adds some stats on data transferred.  No `wlan` interface sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, I can run exactly the same wifi adapter on a Debian VM without hitches. It is indeed the right driver.

You may try to reload the driver,

```
   rmmod rtl8192u
   modprobe rtl8192cu
   iwconfig
```

or you may check whether the device is correctly identified by means of

```
    iw list
```

Also, you may search for error messages,

```
    dmesg -T | grep rtl8192
```

or alternatively

```
    cd /var/log
    grep -nrI rtl8192cu
```

Lastly, you should search for the relevant firmware: in my case,

```
  # modinfo rtl8192cu | head
    filename:       /lib/modules/3.14-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko
    firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_TMSC.bin
    firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_B.bin
    firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw_A.bin
    firmware:       rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
```

If you are missing the firmware, you should proceed as follow:

```
    apt-get install firmware-ralink
```

in Wheezy and later (possibly Etch too, I do not remember).

Comment: Thanks you were right about the firmware not being loaded.  The output from `dmesg` made it clear what was wrong.   The correct firmware package was `firmware-realtek`.  TO get this (for anyone finding this at a later date) I had first to add `non-free` to /etc/apt/sources.list and do an `apt-get update`.